# Call a function in a another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions each one is in a JS file. The JS files are in the same application (WGInsurance) and under the same folder (Scripts).
In the file1 i call the function2 in the file 2, but that doesn't work. Any one have an issue.

File 1 :

```
            reference path="File2.js" />

            if (typeof (WGInsurance) == "undefined")
            { WGInsurance = { __namespace: true }; }

            if (typeof (WGInsurance.Scripts) == "undefined")
            { WGInsurance.Scripts = { __namespace: true }; }

            WGInsurance.Scripts.File1 = {

                myFunction1: function () {
                    WGInsurance.Scripts.File2.myFunction2(); // Is this working ??
                },
                __namespace: true
            };
```

File 2 :

```
            if (typeof (WGInsurance) == "undefined")
            { WGInsurance = { __namespace: true }; }

            if (typeof (WGInsurance.Scripts) == "undefined")
            { WGInsurance.Scripts = { __namespace: true }; }

            WGInsurance.Scripts.File2 = {

                myFunction2: function () {
                    alert("Hello");
                },
                __namespace: true
            };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you include the two javascript files, are you including file 1 first? File 1 needs to load first in order for file 2 to use it.

Comment: The issue is probably the ordering of your files.

Comment: Ok, but I do that with the line : ///reference path="File2.js" /> , or is that only for intellisense ?

Comment: I don't see how ordering would matter, as long as both are referenced before trying to invoke the function (it's not called automatically or anything like that). Might need more insight on how is the page working.

Comment: It is in a package that I deploy in Dynamics CRM. When I do an alert in myfunction1, it works, but not in myfunction2 :)

Comment: And are you sure file 2 is being loaded? If you put the alert at the top of the file does it shows before the function [in question] gets called?

Comment: @JaimeGómez: Actually it does matter. Order of loading in JavaScript matters a lot.

Comment: Yes but in his example you never see the actual function call, so one would assume it happens *after* the files get loaded. They don't have internal dependencies on parsing/interpretation. The framework is actually designed to be loaded unordered (looking at the way the namespace is created).

Comment: I put alert in top of both of the file, but only alert in top of file 1 is shown and only when i click on the button calling the function of file1. Is that clear ? It look like the file1 is loaded when the myfunction1 is called :)

Comment: Well then clearly the other file is not loading, I would guess your reference is only being used for intellisense as you suggested and you need to add it as a "web resource" or something like that. Don't have experience with that technology :(

Comment: Ok, that seems be the right, I will check and keep you in touch :)